# char pointers in c causing segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am pretty new to C so maybe someone can shed some light on why I am getting a segmentation fault with this program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *username = "hello";
    char *other;
    *other = *username;

    return 0;
 }
```

Why is this seg faulting?

Comment: Maybe you want to do `other=username;`, so they're pointing to the same place? Either that, or you have to allocate memory for `other` and use `strcpy`. It depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Where is allocations?

Comment: `other` uninitialize.

Comment: Okay as I understand it char *username = "hello"; automatically allocates a place for the string. However, doesn't *other = *username simply make *other point at the same place *username points? Why is more memory allocation needed?

Comment: `*other = *username` refers to the contents, `other = username` to the pointers. And since you seem to want to have them point to the same place, you would need the latter.

Comment: You might like to read about the dereferencing operator `*`.

Comment: I wish I had a nickel for every time someone tries to use an unallocated pointer. :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`other` hasn't been initialized. It's pointing into some random spot in memory, and you're sticking a character in there.

You'll want to either allocate some space for `other`:

```
char *other = malloc(6);  // or 1, or however much space you'll eventually need
*other = *username;  
// first char at `other` is now 'h'; the rest is unknown. To make it valid string,
// add a trailing '\0'
other[1] = '\0';
```

or if you're trying to make a duplicate string:

```
char *other = strdup(username);
```

or if you're trying to make `other` point to the same place as `username`:

```
char *other = username;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"Okay as I understand it char *username = "hello"; 
 automatically allocates a place for the string."
```

It might be helpful to better define the word 'it' (as used in the above sentence); which is 'the compiler' (without thinking too deeply about the linker and loader).  This means that the compiler prepares a place for the static string "hello" *before* the program is executed.  For example, you can 'grep' the executable and discover that the executable contains the string 'hello'.

*As the program is loaded into memory* by the OS, a 'heap' is established where the program may allocate memory dynamically.

The static string "hello" is not part of the heap; and was not 'allocated' dynamically at run-time.  Rather, it was 'allocated' statically at compile time.

A static value, such as the string "hello", cannot be resized by 'realloc()', or freed by 'free()' because these functions only apply to items allocated from the 'heap', not static "compile-time" allocations.

---

The following code declares a static string "hello".
It also declares a character pointer 'username', and initializes the pointer to point to the static string.

```
char *username = "hello";
```

The following code declares an character pointer 'other', and leaves it uninitialized.  Being that 'other' is uninitialized, and that pointers are always pointing somewhere; it is likely that the uninitialized 'other' pointer is pointing at a random memory location (which does not actually exist).

```
char *other;
```

The following line attempts to copy *one* character ('h') from where username is pointing, to where 'other' is pointing (a random memory location which does not actually exist).

```
*other = *username;
```

This is what generates the 'Segmentation Fault'.

---

FYI, the following statements would cause the pointers 'username' and 'other' to point to the same place, the static string "hello":

```
char *other;
other = username;
```

...which is the same as:

```
char *other = username;
```

---

If you like, you can cause "hello" to be allocated from the heap (at run time) as follows:

```
char *username = strdup("hello");
```

If you would like another copy in 'other':

```
char *other = strdup("hello");
```